# Simplify with TransformationFunctions, Bug?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I want to use custom transformation functions in `Simplify`, but *Mathematica* does not seem to use them properly. Consider the following

```
t1[a] := 1
t2[b] := 0
FullSimplify[a + b, TransformationFunctions -> {t1, t2}]
```

As intended this evaluates to `1`. However, if I add the standard transformation functions nothing happens:

```
FullSimplify[a + b, TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, t1, t2}]
```

This gives `a + b`. Why did *Mathematica* forget about my custom functions? Ideas?

Answer (score 9):

Interesting question.  I don't know if this behavior is intended but I think I can at least give some insight into the problem.

We can use a custom `ComplexityFunction` with an embedded `Print` to take a look at what transformed expressions are tested.

```
cf = (Print[#]; LeafCount[#] + Count[#, _Symbol, {0, -1}]) &;
```

We will also need to make use of `ClearSystemCache[]` to see all simplification attempts.

First without `Automatic`:

```
ClearSystemCache[]
Simplify[a + b, TransformationFunctions -> {t1, t2}, ComplexityFunction -> cf]
```

Observe that for whatever reason `t1` and `t2` are not applied to atomic elements when `Automatic` is included:

```
ClearSystemCache[]
Simplify[a + b, TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, t1, t2}, ComplexityFunction -> cf]
```

While the cause is not clear the solution is: write your transformation functions so that they work on compound expressions.

For example:

```
t3 = # /. {a -> 1, b -> 0} &;

Simplify[a + b, TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, t3}]
```

> ```
>  1
> ```