# How to extract steps from FullSimplify?

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, proof

The answer proposed to the original question doesn't solve it, I need to *understand the results of TraceInternal when used on FullSimplify as a sequence of steps*, which has not been resolved for me.

**Original Question:**

I'm trying to verify an identity:

```
Reduce[(2*n)! (2*n + 1)!/n!^2 == 16^(n) Pochhammer[1/2, n] Pochhammer[3/2, n] && 
  n >= 1, {n}, Integers]
```

Neither `Reduce` nor `Solve` can prove it, they generated these methods:

> Reduce::fexp: Warning: Reduce used FunctionExpand to transform the
>   system. Since *FunctionExpand transformation rules are only
>   generically correct*, the solution set might have been altered.
>
> This system *cannot be solved* with the methods available to Solve.

I randomly decided to try yet another function:

```
FullSimplify[(2*n)! (2*n + 1)!/n!^2 == 16^(n) Pochhammer[1/2, n] Pochhammer[3/2, n], ForAll[{n}, n >= 1 && n \[Element] Integers]]
```

[image]

And I guess it worked, but how and why!? Here's my question:

1. Why did `FullSimplify` work and the others fail?
2. For "theorem proving" functions (e.g. Reduce and FullSimplify) - *Is there any way to see the steps here* or the sow the intermediate results or (i.e. individual transformation steps of FunctionExpand) that it uses/deduces so as to verify it by hand?
3. If not are what are viable packages (or 3rd party software) available that can illustrate human verifiable steps for identities?

Comment: In a nutshell: when you have special functions like `Pochhammer[]` or `Factorial[]` involved, use `FullSimplify[]`.

Answer (score 7):

Can you do the following:

```
Trace[FullSimplify[expr], TraceInternal -> True]
```

or

```
FullSimplify[expr, TransformationFunctions -> {Sow, Automatic}] // Reap
```

References:

[What are the default TransformationFunctions used in Simplify and FullSimplify?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15925/what-are-the-default-transformationfunctions-used-in-simplify-and-fullsimplify)

[Simplify with TransformationFunctions, Bug?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19871/simplify-with-transformationfunctions-bug)

http://12000.org/my_notes/faq/mma_notes/MMA.htm#x1-1600015

http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2006/Sep/msg00670.html

> Information[TraceInternal] "TraceInternal is an option for Trace and
> related functions which, if True or False, specifies whether to trace
> evaluations of expressions generated internally by Mathematica. The
> intermediate Automatic setting traces a selected set of internal
> evaluations including Messages and sets or unsets of visible symbols."
>
> Attributes[TraceInternal] = {Protected}

[Trace of FullSimplify](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27422/trace-of-fullsimplify)

Comment: Thanks @Young, can you elaborate on how to read the output?

Comment: It may be prudent to execute `ClearSystemCache[]` first to avoid earlier computations, if any, causing `FullSimplify` to omit important steps.

Comment: It looks as if you are just quoting from Simon Woods' earlier [answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/27428/3066). If so, you should make a reference to it.

Comment: I still don't understand clearly how to read the output from this (what are the steps?)

Comment: @m_goldberg I guess I found several places using these methods and really this was just to help M.R. on his way